# Azure - System startup task failed with exit code -532462766

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I recently added Azure Caching to my web role, and on redeploy the instance hang in the following status for about 30 minutes:  Busy (Waiting for role to start... System startup tasks are running. [2013-01-25T17:12:53Z])

and then get *System startup task failed with exit code -532462766*, before the instances retry start up.

I have not found anything on this error code, and in dire need on more information.

Comment: May i ask what is the size of your VM?

Comment: add some more details please:  cache settings in web.config, is Cache setup as co-located, dedicated worker role or shared cache?  SDK version?  Also, have you tried to RDP into the instance and view the event logs?

Comment: 2 Small instances; Cache is co-located with cache size of 30%;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem resolved. I needed to set my Web Role storage credentials to use a real storage account instead of development storage. I also selected the check box on the Configurations tab to update the connection string for Diagnostics and Caching with Azure when publishing. Once this was corrected the re-deploy was successful.

Comment: This was very helpful today. I wasted HOURS.